# Mysqli prepared statement: store rows in an array and loop through this array later

Tags: php, arrays, mysqli, while-loop

I use a prepared statement to select rows in a database. Subsequently I would like to echo the individual rows using a while loop. This worked fine, until I tried using a new query within the execution of the while loop (this was necessary because I extract the userID, which I need to transform into a username. I did this by performing a query on the users table, but when I try this, my code doesn't run). I thought I might fix this by storing all the rows in an array, and later in my code loop through this array. However, I can't seem to figure out how to loop through all indices of this array and extract all fields of the row in each instance of the loop.

Thanks a lot! Here is my code:

```
$results = array();

$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT admissionID,userID,description,link,postingdate,compensation FROM replies WHERE projectID=?");
$stmt->bind_param('i',$projectID);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($admissionID,$userID,$description,$link,$postingdate,$compensation);
while($row = $stmt->fetch()){
    $results[] = $row;
}

foreach($results as $result) {
    echo $result['admissionID'];
}
```

Comment: FYI: `mysqli_result::fetch_all` exists, so your `while` loop is kinda unnecessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you need to do it

```
 ids=array();
 while($row = $stmt->fetch()){
    ids[]= $row['userID'];
 }
```

ids is an array and will have all the ids that you need.
But I would say "Dont do it like that", just use a table join to get the username for example may be your case would be like

```
SELECT   replies.admissionID,users.name,replies.userID,replies.description,
replies.link,replies.postingdate,replies.compensation FROM replies, users 
WHERE 
users.name=replies.userID
and replies.projectID=?
```

Comment: Hey thanks for your reply! I'm not familiar with this way of performing a query, but it seems to make sense. However, users.name contains the usernames, while replies.userID contains the user IDs, which are never the same. If I run the code like this, my page stays blank. Is there a step I'm missing?

Comment: You need to iterator of ids instead of results  as the ids are in IDS array now